# Get correct sql command from tupled linq query

Tags: sql, linq, f#

Im wont set SqlDependence to LINQ query.
Work code:

```ml
let SetDependency (dc:DataContext) qr fn= 
    use con=new SqlConnection(dc.Connection.ConnectionString)
    con.Open()
    use cmd=new SqlCommand(dc.GetCommand(qr).CommandText,con)
    let dpn=new SqlDependency(cmd)
    let rec remover=lazy(con.Close()
                         dpn.OnChange.RemoveHandler hnd)
    and hnd=new OnChangeEventHandler(fun ob ev->remover.Force()
                                                fn ev)
    dpn.OnChange.AddHandler hnd
    cmd.ExecuteReader()|>ignore
    remover

//SetDependency sql.DataContext q (fun _ ->"Check..."|>Console.WriteLine)
```

**Problem** -

```ml
let q=query{for s in sql.Stady do
            select s}
q|>string //or (dc:DataContext).GetCommand(q).CommandText
```

> ```ml
> SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[PersonId], [t0].[AfterId] FROM [dbo].[Stady] AS [t0]
> ```

and good work;

```ml
let q1=query{for s in sql.Stady do
             select s.Name}
q1|>string
```

> ```ml
> SELECT [t0].[Name] FROM [dbo].[Stady] AS [t0]
> ```

and good work;

```ml
let q2=query{for s in sql.Stady do
             select (s.Id,s.Name)}
q2|>string
(dc:DataContext).GetCommand(q2).CommandText
```

> `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2[Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.AnonymousObject'2[System.Int64,System.String],System.Tuple'2[System.Int64,System.String]]`

and

> ```ml
> SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
> ```

- and **Not Work**

p.s.
DataContext.Loq writing **correct query** -

> ```ml
> SELECT [t0].[Id] AS [Item1], [t0].[Name] AS [Item2] FROM [dbo].[Stady] AS [t0]
> ```

Comment: I'm not sure how the `SqlDependency` code fits with the rest of the problem. Could you try clarifying that bit? How is it used from the other queries?

Comment: For set SqlDependency on LINQ query im wont get native sql string from query expressions - (dc:DataContext).GetCommand(query).CommandText return wrong result "SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]" if query selected tupled value - ...select (a.id,a.Name).

Comment: ...if selected query contains long type (text,binary...) - not possible set dependency - not support types.

Comment: But how are you calling the `SetDependency ` function?

Comment: let q=query{for s in sql.Stady do
            select s};
SetDependency sql.DataContext q (fun _ ->"Check..."|>Console.WriteLine) //if s not contains long property